# Disabling keyboard in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using the below code which is working fine in chrome, IE but its not working in firefox. Can anybody alter this code such as to work with firefox also.

```
function DisableKeyboardOnMe() {
    if(check1.checked == true) {

    } else if(check1.checked == false) {
        return false;
    }
}

</script>

<asp:CheckBox ID="check1" runat="server"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxt1" runat="server" MaxLength="6" onkeypress="return DisableKeyboardOnMe();" Width="200" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off" onfocus="getFocus(this.id);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know what is the problem with your code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No error but this code is allowing me to use keyboard without checking the checkbox. I need keyboard to be disabled in default. This code works for chrome and IE but not for Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it doesn't do anything...

Comment: @NickBrunt - Why? what's wrong in this code? Its working in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOM element IDs as JS variables.

You need to call `document.getElementById('<%= check1.ClientID %>`)`

However, you actually want to use the `readonly` property instead.

Comment: No read only property allows virtual keyboard but it does not take its value to server side script for processing.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: What I need is just to disable keyboard in default and to enable keyboard if checkbox is checked. And this should not be with `readonly` property.

Comment: @KarsM: Maybe you are confusing `readonly` with `disabled`? If an input is `readonly`, its value is sent to the server.